# How to get information about a file for programming on windows

Tags: c++, winapi

In Linux, we can use the function `stat()` to get a file info, and use the type `st.mode` to judge the rights of the file before we can do some operation on it. In windows, I make a lot of attempts, but little help.

At first, I want to use the function `GetSecurityInfo`, but I can't get the `handle` argument. I did find some solutions, but they all need use `fopen` function which is exactly what I want to avoid. Becasue I want to not do anything substantial with the file until I can determine what permissions it has.

Then I try the `GetFileSecurityA` function, but useless. The following is my code, and I get an error code 998 from `getlasterror`

```
void GetFilesInfo(std::string& path)
{
    char *path1 = new char[1024];
    strcpy(path1, path.c_str());
    SECURITY_INFORMATION FLAGS = ATTRIBUTE_SECURITY_INFORMATION;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR file_security_descriptor = new char[1024];
    LPDWORD minNeedWords = 0;

    if(GetFileSecurityA(path1, FLAGS, file_security_descriptor, 1024, minNeedWords) == 0)
        error_die("GetFileInfo");
    else
        std::cout << file_security_descriptor << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: There's a good discussion of this topic, as well as an example of using `GetFileSecurity`, in http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/08/how-to-check-access-rights/

Comment: `LPDWORD minNeedWords = 0;` passes a null pointer, which is not allowed as the last parameter since it is an output.

Comment: Error 998 is `ERROR_NOACCESS` - Invalid access to memory location. This is because you pass a NULL pointer as the last parameter. `DWORD minNeedWords = 0;` and then `&minNeedWords` for the parameter fixes that. I would also use `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR file_security_descriptor;` and `&file_security_descriptor` for that parameter and `path.c+str()` for the first one. No need to potentially leak memory when you don't have to. `path` should probably also be `const std::string&`.

Comment: That's a needlessly complex way of introducing a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race. Just open the file for the required access and deal with potential errors.

Comment: That's an unacceptable reason. How did you know you have READ access before `stat` executes? But you can ask for getting ACLs by file name.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as previous comments said. I answered the question for completion.

```
#include <Windows.h>
void main()
{
    TCHAR FileName[] = {L"C:\\Users\\Path\\To\\FileName.extension" };
    DWORD LengthNeeded = 0;
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR* sp = (SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR*) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,100);
    BOOL rs = GetFileSecurity(FileName, ATTRIBUTE_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sp,100,&LengthNeeded);
    if (!rs)
    {
        DWORD e = GetLastError();
        //return;
    }
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0,sp);
}
```

[image]